# Android Studio 2.2 Gradle sync failed

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-2.2

I'm trying to re-install Android Studio 2.2 in my formatted computer. I tried installing 2.3 updated version but I got these same errors. So I tried installing 2.2 . When I open a project with an empty activity, Gradle sync fails showing errors in the Message section, as shown in the image. The code in build.gradle (module:app) is given as: `

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.heenamehta.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

`
The code in build.gradle (module: project is given as:)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

How can I solve this problem?[Messages section Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTHh1.png)

Comment: show root `build.gradle` file of your project ?

Comment: Why not update the Android Studio platform and try again?

Comment: Its saying disable offline mode, and sync again. Just click on that and sync it. Have you did this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

In Android Studio go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

Uncheck the 'Offline work' under 'Global Gradle settings'

Connect the internet and sync.

---

Update android gradle plugin to latest version

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
}
```

Comment: From your error log it seems you've offline work enabled for gradle, Try to invalidate caches and restart your studio

Comment: I've just tried that. It doesn't work too. I also tried deleting the gradle-2.14.1 folder from Android Studio files, and extracted again from recent download. That doesn't work too.